# Clearing cache based on usage

Tags: java, algorithm, caching, optimization, ehcache

I'm invoking a web service to populate a cache.

There is a limit on the number of requests that can be sent to the server - 15 requests per hour.

I want minimise the staleness of the cache for users that are invoking the webservice the most.

Below three users access this service :

```
user1 - 10 requests per hour
user2 - 5 requests per hour
user3 - 20 requests per hour

user1 - 29% of requests
user2 - 14% of requests
user3 - 57% of requests
```

Based on this I plan to run a scheduled task that clears the
cache users more frequently for users that are accessing the service a high percentage of times, in the case user3.

Are there alternatives to the approach im taking or existing algorithm I could use, perhaps there is an existing framework I could leverage ?

Comment: are you using memcache or ehcache? You can create user specific keys and set expiry time for those keys as minimum as possible right?

Comment: Will your code ever block the user and wait for a cache update before returning data? Or will it always service the user's request, even if it means returning old data? If there's no big cost to keeping the cache updated, just have your scheduled task update the cache 15 times per hour. That way no user will ever get data that's more than four minutes old.

Comment: @Jim Mischel it will always service the request, and so will potentially return old data. this is what I want to optimize, for users that are regularly access the data, the cache will be refreshed more frequently

Comment: @javadev using ehcache. the expiry time needs to be set at runtime as this parameter will change, I don't think an expiry time can be set at runtime, so it needs to be cleared at a specific point in time

Comment: I think I misunderstood. Are you saying that each user has his own cache of the data that's held by the web service? Do you have some central traffic cop controlling calls to that web service? I think you need to be more specific about how your application is structured.

Comment: Interesting question! Is each user accessing the same data? If yes, wouldn't it be better to refresh the values more often that are requested more often? What happens when one user scans the cache contents?